# dynamic labels (character vetor) for plot in R

Tags: r, plot, label

I feel pretty dumb for this question, but can't get my head around it: I craete a boxplot in R. Sometimes I have 5 underlying dataframes, sometimes more or less. Each dataframe results in a boxplot. So each boxplot should have a label in the form of `Label 1`, `Label 2`, `Label 3`, etc.

Since I only know the number of boxplots during runtime, I obviously cannot hardcode the labels as below:

```
boxplot(boxList, names=c('Label 1', 'Label 2')
```

So how can I dynamically create a character vector given a variable `count` indicating the number of boxplots.

For instance `count = 3`. Result should be: `c('Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3')`

Comment: You're looking for `paste('Label', sep = ' ', 1:count)`

Comment: ah nice. so easy. dont know why I didn't find anything. have to revise my google-skills, i guess. thanks! can be entered as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste` function will do, as it is vectorized

```
> count <- 3
> paste('Label', 1:count)
```

**Output**:

```
[1] "Label 1" "Label 2" "Label 3"
```

'Label' is pasted with every element of `1:count` vector, separated by a space character (default for sep argument).